# Writing value of LastPage to external file

Tags: lastpage

How can I write the final value of LastPage (\pageref{LastPage}) to an external file (knowing that it needs 2-3 compiliations of the document)? (I need it to adapt a .cls file.)

[Update 2016-01-29, 13:30]

Found the following solution using the *refcount* package:

```
\RequirePackage{lastpage}
\RequirePackage{refcount}

@write\tocfile{}{%
\number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}
```

Thx for the answers.

Comment: Do you know how to write to external file? if yes just use `\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\mywrite{\thepage}}`

Comment: @m42 I would not try to re-invent the wheel. Just use `\zref@extract{LastPage}{abspage}` where needed within your class file.

Comment: @AlexG I gave it a try, but it didn't work in my setting. I tried

    **@write\tocfile{}{\number\numexpr\zref@extract{LastPage}{abspage}}**

and got a "Missing number, treated as zero" error message

Comment: @m42: Don't write the `LastPage` information into some external file. That has been done for you already. Simply insert `\zref@extract{LastPage}{abspage}` at the place within your `*.cls` where you *need* this information.

Comment: @AlexG Well, I need this in the `*.cls` file to write the `LastPage` value into an external file. I.e., part of functionality of the `*.cls` file is to create an external file with some content (used for other purposes).

Comment: @m42 : Ok, I see. See my edited answer, you will have to open some file you want to write to.

Comment: AlexG Somehow I cannot get it running with your revised version. Providing a MWE is tedious, so I will live for now with the refcount solution until it works with your zref suggestion. (My current problem is that writing to the file happens in `\maketitle` and this doesn't work well with `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: So you try to modify the `\maketitle` command of an existing class file?

Comment: `\makefile` happens after `\begin{document}`.  Therefore, you don't need `\AtBeginDocument` if you modify `\maketitle`. See my edit.

Comment: @AlexG Thanks! I now got it running. As you said, I removed `AtBeginDocument`. In my case I need to use `\protected@write` instead of `\immediate\write` due to the use of several other variables I need to expand.

Answer (score 2):

The package `zref`, using the `lastpage` module is an option. The information about the page count is written to the `*.aux` file.

Since a class file is to be modified, the "Programmer's" interface of `zref`, `\zref@extract{<reference name>}{<property name>}` should be used to retrieve the information.

The `*.aux` file is read on subsequent compilation runs just before starting to typeset the document, making the information stored in the `*.aux` file available.

Custom auxiliary output files need to be opened first before they can be written to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[lastpage]{zref}

\newwrite\mytocfile
\immediate\openout\mytocfile=mytocfile.txt

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%overwrite the `\maketitle' definition of the class file
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\let\maketitleOrig\maketitle
\def\maketitle{%
  \immediate\write\mytocfile{The last page number is: \zref@extract{LastPage}{page}.}%
  \immediate\write\mytocfile{The total page count is: \zref@extract{LastPage}{abspage}.}%
  \maketitleOrig%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother

%\makeatletter
%
%%this my go into your cls file
%\newwrite\mytocfile
%\immediate\openout\mytocfile=mytocfile.txt
%\AtBeginDocument{%
%  \immediate\write\mytocfile{The last page number is: \zref@extract{LastPage}{page}.}%
%  \immediate\write\mytocfile{The total page count is: \zref@extract{LastPage}{abspage}.}%
%}  
%
%\makeatother

\title{The Document Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

{\huge
The last page number is \makeatletter\zref@extract{LastPage}{page}.\makeatother

The absolute page count is \makeatletter\zref@extract{LastPage}{abspage}.\makeatother
}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\kant[1-10]
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\kant[11-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think `\immediate` may not be the best option here. Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330691/13173